# Link from Lightbox to Lightbox of different sizes

Tags: php, javascript, navigation, lightbox

I have Login and Sign Up forms.
Both are opening in Lightbox.
Login have Link to Sign Up and vice versa. 
Links are working properly, but the issue is sign up box's height is 600px while that of login is 250px. So, When navigating from login to sign up, its opening with 250 height and scroll bar appears which gives ugly look.

I want Sign up should open with 600px height even when I am clicking it from login which have 250px height.

I am using `thickbox.js` for lightbox

What I tried is:

```
function signup() { 
    window.location="sign_up.php?TB_iframe=true&height=600&width=330";   
}
```

Comment: which lightbox are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your forms from same domain then you can try this code before navigating iframe to another link:

```
window.parent.$('#TB_window').animate({
    height: 600
});
```

So if you changing iframe location with `signup` function then you should modify it

```
function signup() { 
    window.parent.$('#TB_window').animate({
        width: 330
        height: 600
    });
    window.location="sign_up.php?TB_iframe=true&height=600&width=330";   
}
```

Comment: where should I use this? if you dont mind can you please give me the full code.

Comment: my forms are from same domain.. same directory

Comment: animation is working but the form is displayed inside its previous size only.. its not stretching to 600. :(

Comment: Little Modification required.. so, i am updating this anyways this answer helped me.. thanks ant_Ti :)

Comment: add `window.parent.$('#TB_iframeContent').animate({
        width: 330
        height: 600
    });` before `window.location` since this thickbox has Iframe in it